# Connection string int asp error

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, database, connection-string

I have error in line 20 here is the error line:

`int temp = Convert.ToInt32(com.ExecuteScalar().ToString());`

Page for my code: [Pastebin](http://pastebin.com/vLcMVENi)

Page error that show up:[Pastebin](http://pastebin.com/3uKTxFAC)

Comment: What is the value of `com.ExecuteScalar().ToString()` and what is your `CurrentCulture`? Please show your code and error message as a text here. Since I'm at work now, pastebin domain was blocked by firewall.

Comment: it's telling you exactly what's wrong:  `Unclosed quotation mark after the character string ''.`

Comment: try to fix you select like this: `select count(*) from SystemMemberInfo where Username='"+ TextBoxUserName.Text +"'";`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error says:

> Unclosed quotation mark after the character string ''.

Your SQL command is:

```
string checkuser = "select count(*) 
                    from SystemMemberInfo 
                    where Username="+ TextBoxUserName.Text +"'";
```

If you look at your string, you'll notice that you have a quotation mark at the end of your WHERE clause, but not at the beginning.

Your WHERE clause should look more like:

```
where Username='"+ TextBoxUserName.Text +"'";
```

Please also don't do queries like this, they are susceptible to [SQL Injection attacks](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=mysql%20sql%20injection%20%5Bc%23%5D).

Comment: Nope http://pastebin.com/iDCEwp9U

Comment: @herobrinebrotherzoro, actually, that's a different error discovered because we resolved the first one. You should create a new question for that. Also, including the SQL that is failing is usually required to provide assistance.

Comment: Ok i think it helped but no the same error look: http://pastebin.com/R1f77QiF and i dont care if it will be injectable my website wil be private no one will know.

Comment: @herobrinebrotherzoro Not trying to be mean, but read the error, then look at your code. If you can't figure it out, let me know.

Comment: Ok thanks i will try to make a new question.

Comment: @herobrinebrotherzoro, before you create a new question, read the error and try to fix it yourself

Answer (score 0):

Your error is on the SQL query `where` statement.

your code is:

```
string checkuser = "select count(*) from SystemMemberInfo where Username="+ TextBoxUserName.Text +"'";
```

To correct it, write it this way:

```
string checkuser = "select count(*) from SystemMemberInfo where Username='" + TextBoxUserName.Text + "'";
```

Comment: http://pastebin.com/iDCEwp9U